# How do I go about listing all of the installed packages and versions on mac os x?

Tags: macos, versions

I want to list all of the applications and versions installed on my mac.  Stuff like perl, php, etc., not the stuff you see in the Applications directory...  Is there a unix command for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly a *unix* command but:

`system_profiler -detailLevel full > myreport.txt` might be a good start.

There's an option to only list software (as there is an option to ouput xml) (read the manpage for the precise syntax).
If you're using macports you could just run `port installed`.

Answer (score 5):

pkgutil --packages
or
cat /Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist

Answer (score 0):

You can use command for get installed apps list

Json and xml output is available.

```
system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType -xml

system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType -json
```