# How can I discover what apps are installed on OS X using Objective C or Macruby?

Tags: objective-c, macos, macruby

could you tell me please - which object and which method can i use to fetch information about installed applications on OSX with objective c or macruby?

Answer (score 4):

You can just call the Apple command-line tool `system_profiler`, e.g.

`% system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType`

For C or Objective-C you could use `system()` to do this.

For more info:

`% man system`

`% man system_profiler`

Comment: +1 solid answer (also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518610/how-do-i-go-about-listing-all-of-the-installed-packages-and-versions-on-mac-os-x/2518684#2518684)

Comment: To make it easier to parse the results in code, you can use the `-xml` flag to `system_profiler` to get property list output.

Answer (score 4):

If you meant to list all of GUI apps, you can use [Launch Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html). For the list of functions, see [the reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html).

**Do not manually list** `.app` **bundles!** It's already done by the system, and you just have to query it.
There is a command-line program called `lsregister` at

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister
```

which can be used to get the detailed dump of the Launch Service database. This tool is sometimes helpful,
but don't depend on that in a shipping program,

Answer (score 3):

OS X doesn't really have a notion of "installing an app". OS X applications are self contained bundles that appear in the Finder as a single virtual file. There's no central registry, just a convention that applications are placed in /Applications or ~/Applications for a per user "install".

About the best you can do will be enumerate those directories for their contents, and every ".app" directory you find is an application. It will not be a exhaustive (I often run small apps from e.g. my Desktop if I've just downloaded them).

Comment: There **is** a centralized registry.

Comment: Not that refers to actual "installed" applications. For example, the SPApplications set in system_profiler will contain e.g. iPhone applications you've developed, which can't really be considered an OS X installed application.

Answer (score 2):

I moved in a following way:

- execute command `system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType -xml`
  from code. Key `SPApplicationsDataType` means that only application data is required. `-xml` means that I expect to see xml result for easier parsing.
- parse result array

Here you can find nice example regarding command execution from code: [Execute a terminal command from a Cocoa app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412562/execute-a-terminal-command-from-a-cocoa-app/696942#696942)

Total code example is looked like following:

```
NSStirng * commangString = @"system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType -xml"; 
NSData * resultData = [CommandLineTool runCommand:commangString];
NSArray * appArray = [PlistManager objectFromData:resultData];
// parse array of NSDictionaries here ....



// method from PlistManager
+ (id) objectFromData: (NSData *) data {
    NSString *errorString = nil;
    NSPropertyListFormat format;
    id object = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainers format:&format errorDescription:&errorString];
    if (!errorString) {
        return object;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error while plist to object conversion: %@", errorString);
        return nil;
    }
}

// runCommand method was used from post I mentioned before
```

Comment: what namespace do i need to import in order to use CommandLineTool and PlistManager

Answer (score 1):

Use Spotlight via NSMetadataQuery.

You can view the results you'll get using mdfind at the command line:

mdfind "kMDItemContentType == 'com.apple.application-bundle'"

Works like a charm and very very fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier:@"com.google.Chrome"];
```

This would return a path to `Google Chrome` app if it is installed, `nil` otherwise.

If you don't know the `BundleID`, there are two options to find it:

1) Open `.plist` file of the app by right-clicking the app icon and choosing `Show Package Contents` option.

Default path to Chrome .plist is `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/Info.plist`

2) Use `lsregister` alongside with `grep`.

Try typing the following into the `Terminal` app, you will find the BundleID there:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -dump | grep -i chrome
```

Answer (score -2):

As it is a unix-like OS there is no real way of telling what you have installed (unless of course you have control of the other app - then there is a lot of ways of doing this for obvious reasons).

Generally apps get put into /Applications or ~/Applications BUT you can run it from anywhere and not those folders (just like a unix machine)