# Need Objective C API to list all apps installed by a user on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am searching if there is an API

Q1) that can tell who installed a given app or 
Q2) that list of all the apps installed by given user

Hi I already looked at [How can I discover what apps are installed on OS X using Objective C or Macruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765063/how-can-i-discover-what-apps-are-installed-on-os-x-using-objective-c-or-macruby)

Already have gone through Launch Service, which is mostly to deal with "Open with " action , it does give all installed apps, but I couldn't find any property like which user installed that app.

For Q1, how good or bad would be to locate the .app file in /Application and then try to get FileInfo about that and figure out which user created that file ?

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that there's some API can provide you that kind of information. Application in iOS run in Sandbox mode. That mean each application have their own area to work and can touch nothing to other app (without some special protocol provided by apple)

You can find more of it here.

https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/

Comment: This question is about OS X though, not iOS.